# Multilevel modeling for only two data points

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am struggling with how to conduct multilevel modeling for my current data (I am fairly new to multilevel modeling).

I have Event as an IV (bad event = 1, good event = 2) and have well-being as a DV. Here, I would like to assess whether the mediator (psychological trait) would moderate the relationship between IV and DV.

IV was within-person as I asked participants to rate their well-being for both good and bad events. Therefore, I thought the data was nested in that two data points were nested in participants.

Therefore, is it right for me to use multilevel modeling with individual participants as a random intercept and run my model?

```
model <- lme(AFFECT ~ Event * NFC, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = data_long, 
             na.action = na.omit, control = list(opt = "optim"), method = "ML")
```

Any suggestions are helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's typically fine. 2 observations per cluster is not much, but you can estimate random intercept with them. Not a random slope though, but you weren't planning to, so that should not be a problem. An alternative approach would be to use a single-level regression with clustered standard errors.

Comment: This is discussed in Oberpriller, J., de Souza Leite, M., & Pichler, M. (2022). Fixed or random? On the reliability of mixed‐effects models for a small number of levels in grouping variables. Ecology and Evolution, 12(7), e9062.https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ece3.9062

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the share.